# how to access an ecs task with out using any port

Tags: port, amazon-ecs, portforwarding

I have an ecs task running and to access that currently, I am using:

```
http://domainname:port
```

I don't want to mention the port in the URL when I am using `http://domainname` it should automatically redirect to port . What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The default port for HTTP traffic is port `80`. If you try to attempt an HTTP connection without specifying a port, then port `80` will be used. So if you want to access your URL without specifying a port, you need to configure it to use port `80`.

Comment: Can we add any other port in url and then redirect it to that specific port? Ex. My application is running on port 5000, then in domain i can add http://domainname:5000 which will forward request to 5000 port on my container?